# how to setup default source encoding in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

Ruby has default source encoding to ASCII, to alter the source encoding, it is necessary to use magic encoding comments on the header of each file will help the Ruby interpreter to load file in that encoding.

I've done my homework, I know there is [three encoding](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) in Ruby and the external or internal encoding which could be set by switches)

To config `Ruby` with default source encoding (such as utf-8) without any touch on my program files, I could use `Ruby -e` to launch my files.

How to enable this in a `Rails` environment such in `unicorn` or `rails` wrapepr?

Comment: There is a gem for this purpose, let me find it and get back to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804742/ruby-how-to-add-encoding-utf-8-automatically

Comment: I know this gem, it adds the magic comments in every file in my repo,  but this is not the solution I am looking for. I am looking for a zero config solution.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908774/set-global-default-encoding-for-ruby-1-9

Comment: Seems to be the real answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494613/heroku-and-rails-how-to-set-utf-8-as-the-default-encoding