# Rails, Unable to store Foreign accented words in PSQL DB with utf-8 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, encoding, psql, latin1

This is my first time running into such issue so if m not thorough enough I apologize for that.The project I have requires me to store data in French language, initially the encoding was set to utf-8 in database.yml however when I try and change that to latin 1 I get an error saying:

```
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  encoding "LATIN1" does not match locale "en_US.UTF-8"
```

The data that is stored in the utf-8 encoded database is in the form of broken special characters and not in the form of the actual foreign accented letters, I have googled a lot but have found solutions like recreating the template1 database with new encoding.
I want to ask the following points:

1. How will recreating template1 database effect my existing databases on that template with utf-8 encoding (in case I want to retain all those as well).
2. Is there a way to create an additional template databases (apart from template0, template1) as I dont want to lose the existing en_US.utf-8 databases on that template.

Also is this the right approach or is there any other way this can be achieved. I have been stuck on this issue for quite a while now.
Any sort of help will be hugely appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Also I would like to know if by any way can we specify encoding/charset for a specific schema inside db template1.

Comment: It seems to me that using UTF-8 throughout your application stack would be the best option here.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Can you please elaborate a bit what can be the methodology for that , previously I had utf-8 encoding and I was unable to properly store french accented characters.

Comment: That may have been the point at which to raise a question. UTF-8 is entirely capable of storing characters with French diacritics. I've never had a problem with Rails on PostgreSQL storing European or Asian character sets out-of-the-box, so I have no experience in diagnosing what that problem may have been, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidAldridge oh, when I have my app encoding set to utf-8, words in french language having french accented characters appear as special characters in DB and are retrieved and displayed as special characters as well. Any idea what can be the issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'd better ask a new question on that.

Comment: You can't really just change the encoding in your `database.yml` without changing the actual database encoding. Please show the output of `SHOW server_encoding;` when connected to the database.

Comment: @CraigRinger "UTF8" is the response I got upon running the above command

Comment: @ZaeemAsif Ok so you'd better use utf8 encoding on the client connection (database.yml) too, otherwise some existing data in the db might not be readable. This should be the default. You then just have to make sure data coming from the browser is utf8 and convert it if it isnt.

Comment: @CraigRinger convert the latin1 to utf8 and store it and then decode when requested?

Comment: @ZaeemAsif If the client browser sends latin1 then yes convert to utf-8 and store urf-8 in the db. If the client browser http headers declare it expects latin1 then encode utf8 to latin1 for sending. Rails should have helpers for all this. I don't know the details as I don't use rails. But use utf8 internally in your rails app and in the database.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks a lot for that help and giving me a direction, will surely try it right now. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Per comment discussion it sounds like your DB is in UTF-8, i.e. `SHOW server_encoding` or `SELECT current_setting('server_encoding')` returns `utf-8`.

If so, you should leave your encoding in `database.yml` as `utf-8` (or unspecified which should I think mean that it uses the server encoding).

Then you should use UTF-8 throughout your application. Run your application in a `UTF-8` locale to ensure your collations are correct.

When dealing with web browers that request non-UTF-8 encodings, you can and should decode their responses into UTF-8, and when you're sending data to the browser, you should transform it from UTF-8 into the browser's requested encoding. The browser tells you what encoding it wants in its HTTP headers.

Most (all?) browsers support UTF-8, though, so instead you can *tell the browser to decode your pages as UTF-8 and to send all GET/POST requests to you in UTF-8 too*, using headers like `Accept-Charset` and the charset option of `Content-Type`, e.g. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. This is what I suggest doing.

I don't know the specifics of how Rails does encodings/charsets, as I work on the database side, but that should get you started. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6494613/398670) is about a pretty old Rails version, but mentions setting `config.encoding` in `config/application.rb`. You'll also need to make sure your Ruby files are marked as UTF-8 with `#encoding: utf-8` if they actually incorporate text outside the 7-bit ASCII range.

Try to avoid setting HTTP headers directly and doing direct encoding/decoding. The framework should have a way to do that for you. Find it and use it. Then use utf-8 throughout the application and database.